# How to create accurate RBD simulations that are perfectly synced to sound and collide with each sound beats?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigid-body-simulation, audio

Hey Blender Community!,

I recently stumbled upon this youtube short by this famous artist using rigid body sims to create this amazing animation with the sim reacting with music notes. I was wondering how is it possible to create such an effect, especially making the rbd sim collide with objects in tune to music at the exact second. I tried it myself but couldn't exactly match up the sync between the physics and the music. Would really love the input and expertise from you lot!

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/nAGIh5NymL8

This is what I've tried so far, without much luck I can't get them to perfect sync.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK it is just tedious work. Play the sound (e.g. by speaker) and start your rigid body sim with e.g. a sphere. If the first note hits, stop the animation and add your first rigid body object exactly on that place. Then start rigid body from start again and keep going until music finishes.

Comment: It is most likely not even a rigid body simulation, just a keyframed animation made to look like rigid body simulation. Or tedious work. Or both. But I doubt that a real simulation could be looped so seamlessly. Maybe with a sim as a starting point, then baked to keyframes and tweaked to fit perfectly. You should ask the creator.

Comment: yeah, you are right, might be even just animated.